# AttributeError: 'Combobox' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to display the output(string) in the combobox but I keep receiving this error.

df3 = dataframe of two columns

```
def callback1(eventObject):

   for col in df3.loc[df3["Customer Name"].eq(cbox.get())].iterrows():
       print(col)
       lbox.append(col)

cbox = Combobox(window,width=30, textvariable=filter_mode, state="readonly", values=list(df["Customer Name"].unique()))
cbox.place(x=150,y=60)

cbox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", callback1)

lbox = Combobox(window, width=30, values=list(df3["MFG Device"].unique()))
lbox.place(x=150,y=90)
```

Comment: See the [official document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#combobox) on how to use `ttk.Combobox`.

Comment: Did you want `lbox.config(values=list(df3.loc[df3["Customer Name"]==cbox.get()]["MFG Device"]))` instead of the for loop?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `append()` to `ttk.Combobox`.

You can only assing new list with all values or get old values, convert to list, `append()` or `extend()` to this list and assing back this list.

```
def callback1(event):
    data = list(lbox['values'])
    data.append("new value")
    lbox['values'] = data
```

or many items

```
def callback1(event):
    data = list(lbox['values'])
    data.extend( ["value1", "value2", "value3" ])
    lbox['values'] = data
```

BTW: if you keep original list which you add to `Combobox` then you can use it also to replace values

```
ldata = ['A', 'B', 'C']
lbox = ttk.Combobox(window, values=ldata)
```

and later

```
ldata.append(...)
lbox['values'] = ldata
```

---

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

# --- functions ---

#def callback1(event):
#    ldata.append(filter_mode.get())
#    lbox['values'] = ldata
    
def callback1(event):
    data = list(lbox['values'])
    
    #data.append(filter_mode.get())
    data.extend( ["value1", "value2", "value3" ])
    
    lbox['values'] = data

# --- main ---

window = tk.Tk()

filter_mode = tk.StringVar(window)

cdata = ['A', 'B', 'C']
cbox = ttk.Combobox(window, textvariable=filter_mode, state="readonly", values=cdata)
cbox.pack()

cbox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", callback1)

ldata = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
lbox = ttk.Combobox(window, values=ldata)
lbox.pack()

window.mainloop()
```